# uniq -c is not working with awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, gawk

I have a log file with multiple data i want to filter on DHCPREQUEST IP from that file and I want to count how many time a IP request for that service content in log file is like this :-

```
Mar 22 11:20:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:19:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.2 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:18:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.2 from aa:00:00:00:17:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:16:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:15:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:14:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:12:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:11:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
```

Using this code I am printing count with grep IP but its showing count 1 for duplicate IP also please suggest what I am doing wrong

```
five_min='Mar 22 11:15:34' 
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$five_min" < "$line" ]] 
    then
        echo "$line" | grep DHCPREQUEST  | awk -F  " " '{print $8 }' | uniq -c
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: it is useless to redefine `-F " "` which is standard implementation. Also, you are piping inside the awk call: depending on your flavor, that may cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following single `awk` may help you on same too.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){array[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++} END{for(i in array){print array[i],i}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){  array[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++  }
END{
  for(i in array)                         {  print array[i],i                    }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You're running the command on a single line, so it makes sense that you're getting 1.

Having the following **test.txt**:

```
Mar 22 11:20:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:20:35 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
Mar 22 11:20:36 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
```

The command:

```
grep DHCPREQUEST test | awk '{print $8}' | uniq -c
```

prints:

```
3 10.1.1.1
```

Comment: using this way but still not getting right count for duplicate ip

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible content of your file?

Comment: its same like you are using in test file

Comment: @Vijay Divide the pipes - check what's the output of `grep`, then pipe `awk`.

Comment: Mar 22 11:20:34 DHCP-IP dhcp: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.1 from aa:00:00:00:00:00 (pc) via 10.1.1.2
 : give me this output of grep and awk print  1  10.1.1.1

Comment: @Vijay How many lines you're getting back from `grep DHCPREQUEST test`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167606/discussion-between-vijay-and-maroun).

Comment: @Vijay, could you please post more useful inputs in your post, so that we could understand your requirement better?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 problem was loop variable line because of loop line repersents one line on each loop so that uniq is not working now i store the data in temp file then uniq is working now thanks.

Comment: @Vijay, we all are trying to learn here by putting effort, to be honest your information was not enough. I will still say re-phrase your question and do let us know what is needed so that other people who read this thread will be benefited too from this.

Comment: @Vijay, please add expected output too here and let me know then.

Comment: @Vijay, for your input my `awk` is working perfectly, please be more clear what is NOT working with it?

Comment: @Vijay, please select any of the answer as correct answer too, cheers :)